# Checking for uniqueness in combination of two fields

Tags: c#

I have table clientcontactcompany table and checking for if combination of email Address and clientcompanyId exist. I have set a unique constraint on both the fields. I am trying to write logic in my repository layer

Client company contact class

```
public partial class ClientCompanyContact
{
    public ClientCompanyContact()
    {
        FxforwardTrade = new HashSet<FxforwardTrade>();
        Fxoption = new HashSet<Fxoption>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientCompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneDirect { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneMobile { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneOther { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    public bool Authorized { get; set; }
    public byte[] UpdateTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedByAuthUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public bool RecNotifications { get; set; }
    public bool RecAmreport { get; set; }
    public int? AuthUserId { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public bool? PrimaryContact { get; set; }
    public bool RecActivityReport { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string Aspnumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AspcreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastTelephoneChangeDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastEmailChangeDate { get; set; }
    public string BloombergGpi { get; set; }
    public string NiNumber { get; set; }

    public AuthUser AuthUser { get; set; }
    public ClientCompany ClientCompany { get; set; }
    public AuthUser UpdatedByAuthUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FxforwardTrade> FxforwardTrade { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fxoption> Fxoption { get; set; }
}
```

Client contact repository

```
public IGenericRepo<ClientCompanyContact> ClientCompanyContactRepository =>
        _clientCompanyContactRepository = _clientCompanyContactRepository ?? new GenericRepo<ClientCompanyContact>(Context);
```

This is what I tried snd not compiling . What’s the right of doing it

```
   public async Task<bool> UniqueEmail(string email, string ClientCompanyId)
    {
        return await ClientCompanyContactRepository.Get().Where(x => x.Email == email && x.ClientCompanyId = ClientCompanyId);
    }
```

Comment: `x.ClientCompanyId = ClientCompanyId1` is an assignment, not a comparison. An assignment returns the assigned result, which is an `int`, not a `bool`, which is why it's causing an error.

Comment: Also, you have the parameter `ClientCompanyId` passed in as a `string`, but it appears to be an `int` in the class, so you'll need to do a conversion on the string first as well.

Comment: You should post the error(s) that you're getting if what you've tried isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, pass the ClientCompanyID in as an int, then you're missing an equal sign, should be:

```
x => x.Email == email && x.ClientCompanyId == ClientCompanyId
```

Comment: Is ClientCompanyContactRepository.Get().where correct ? The another thing is that the entire expression should result in true or false

Comment: `x.ClientCompanyId` is an `int`, and `ClientCompanyId` is a `string`. Are you sure this is correct? Shouldn't it at least be `== int.Parse(ClientCompanyId)`?

Comment: return await ClientCompanyContactRepository.Get().Where(x => x.Email == email && x.ClientCompanyId == ClientCompanyId);

Comment: ClientcompanyId is and int. my mistake

Comment: I am getting the following error when implementing the above. IEnumerable<ClientCompanyContact> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter and no accessible method GetAwaiter aceepting a first 
argument of of type IEnumerable<ClientCompanyContact> could be found

Answer (score 1):

You have few small but deadly  mistakes in your code.

The method should look more like this.

```
public async Task<bool> UniqueEmail(string email, int clientCompanyId)
{
    var count = await ClientCompanyContactRepository.Get()
         .Count(x => x.Email == email && x.ClientCompanyId == clientCompanyId);
    return count < 2;
}
```

Please note that `.Count(x => ...)` could be `.Where( x => ...).Count()`.

Changes:

1. Pass `clientCompanyId` as `int`, so '`int ClientCompanyId`'
2. You need to return a bool not a list objects, so '`bool anyMatching = x.Any(...); return !anyMatching`'.
3. Parameter names should start with common letter, so '`int clientCompanyId`'
4. Comparison uses `==`, not `=` so '`== ClientCompanyId`'
5. If `Get` is `async` it should be `GetAsync`, or even `GetAllAsync`.

---

Update: it seems that Get is not async. Let's drop all async parts.

```
public bool UniqueEmail(string email, int clientCompanyId)
{
    var count = ClientCompanyContactRepository.Get()
         .Count(x => x.Email == email && x.ClientCompanyId == clientCompanyId);
    return count < 2;
}
```

---

Please note we don't know what `Get()` returns so we don't know if the filtering will happen in memory or in the database.

I suspect that `Get()` may return all records so the filtering will happen in memory. You may want to move `UniqueEmail` into the repository.*

Comment: Getting the following error when implementing the above 
bool does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter and no accessible method GetAwaiter aceepting a first 
argument of of type bool could be found

Comment: I added non async version.

Comment: Thank you! I really needed this :)

Comment: I am not sure why you did !anyMatching. Shouldnt be returning anyMatching

Comment: Ahh...wait. This part may need changing. Does `UniqueEmail` answer the following question: Is this email unique among all contacts for a given compnay already in the contact list?